# How to set up Redis cache for Fireworks app on Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl, redis, signalr

I downloaded the sample fireworks app from
https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Samples/Fireworks

And then deploy it to Azure. But it does not work. I suspect I did not initialize it properly.

Could anyone please help?

Here're the errors:

[image]

And my init code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Firework.Startup))]

namespace Firework
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("fireworks.redis.cache.windows.net", 6379, "UaI+1bJq79dTEJiP0jZHAcBRLjT+lR9rXTxtUl1op1o=", "Fireworks");
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

My Azure:

[image]

[image]

Update 1: Is there a way for me to enable the Non-SSL port.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the non-SSL port (**6379**) disabled in the Azure portal, but that's the port you're trying to connect to in your code. I would suggest enabling that port first and ensure it works without SSL, then try to get the app running on the SSL port (**6380**) after that.

[image]

Comment: I tried, but the portal won't let me enable the Non-SSL port. Please see my update 1 screenshot. Thanks for helping.

Comment: At the bottom of the 'blade' for your redis instance, there is a "Configuration" section and "Access Ports" is one of the options. Hope it works for you!